# AMP How to get event.valueAsNumber for select

Tags: amp-html

I want to get a `<select>` value and assign it to an amp-state.

In theory I should be able to do event.valueAsNumber as documented [here.](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-actions-and-events.md)

However I get "null" back when attempting to use this property.

[Codepen.](https://codepen.io/powlo/pen/PJjGXa?editors=1000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a bug as `event.valueAsNumber` should work. A workaround is to manually convert the value to an integer using the unary `+` operator:

```
 <select on="change:AMP.setState({product: {quantity: +event.value}})">
```

I've filed a bug [here](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/11513).